# How do I just retrieve the specific value enclosed within the tags using regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex

So I'm pretty new to both python and regex, and I was assigned a web scraping task today as a one off, to retrieve one value, from one table, in one website. What I have now is a variable called "data" which is assigned this value.

`<td class="SRTgroup--table__cell--4w5578xr">0.24985</td>`

I've been trying to wrap my head around regex and forming a statement so that I can just retrieve the "0.24985" value from the string. Is it possible to do this using a regex statement? Any help would be appreciated, and I apologize in advance if I am doing something terribly wrong with how I'm going about this. This is my first day using python and regex. Thanks in advance!

Comment: _Don't_ use regex here; use the Beautiful Soup library instead.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Would you be able to show me how I can do this with beautifulsoup?

Comment: Check the duplicate link at the top of your question.  The accepted answer shows you how to do it.